# Windows Search Indexer keeps taking the focus

Tags: windows-7, windows-search, media-player-classic

I am trying to watch a video with MPC and then Windows Search Indexer keeps taking the focus.. how do I prevent it from doing that? running Windows 7 with x64

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean it keeps taking focus? The Windows Search Indexer runs as a service with no visible UI except the control panel applet that lets you configure it's settings.

Comment: MPC actually says that the Windows Search Indexer took focus.. basically I keep jumping out of fullscreen mode.. whcih sucks..